# Add nf-if condition for custom directive property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

Below is the example of my custom directives

```
<div ng-if="activitedTab == 'individual-accounts'">
    <ind-table tmodel="choosenInfo.section1.src" ttype="{{activitedTab}}" clickaction="popup"></ind-table>
</div>
```

How can i put a condition for the property **clickaction** so that this property could be included only if the value of scope variable contentLength is true. I tried below way.

```
<div ng-if="activitedTab == 'individual-accounts'">
    <ind-table tmodel="choosenInfo.section1.src" ttype="{{activitedTab}}" ng-if="contentLength" clickaction="popup"></ind-table>
</div>
```

But if the value of contentLength become false then entire section is not displayed. I just want to exclude clickaction property if the value of contentLength is false.

Comment: what is the type of the `popup` ? you can use a ternary if `contentLength` exists you send `popup` if not send an empty array (if popup is an array for example)

Comment: If **clickaction** is in your own custom directive, then just add the condition within the logic itself.

Comment: If you absolutely need to remove it from the element, you'll need to create a second directive that re-compiles the element whenever your contentLength value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ng-if condition from the custom directive and use the ternary operator as-

clickaction="contentLength > 0 ? popup : '' "